# React.createElement - converting jsx to normal function calls on a large scale

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How should I convert jsx libraries and elements to normal function calls? Is there any difference between the following two code samples (example simple app component with react-router components is just an example, could be anything, or any element types like 'div', or 'p', or other jsx library):

```js
// normal jsx
const PublicApp = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  </Switch>
)
```

```js
// desired api
const PublicApp = () =>
  Switch(
    {},
    Route({ path: '/register', component: Register }),
    Route({ path: '/login', component: Login }),
    Route({ path: '/about', component: About }),
    Redirect({ to: '/login' })
  )
```

```js
// required helpers
import { createElement as h } from 'react'
import * as ReactRouter from 'react-router'

export const Switch = (props, ...children) =>
  h(ReactRouter.Switch, props, ...children)

export const Route = (props, ...children) =>
  h(ReactRouter.Route, props, ...children)

export const Redirect = (props, ...children) =>
  h(ReactRouter.Redirect, props, ...children)

export const Div = (props, ...children) => h('div', props, ...children)

. . . .
```

Both seem to work fine. Any problem with doing this on a large scale? Also, seems sort of silly to have to manually wrap every element type. Is there a better way than using a converter like this:

```js
const converter = el => (props, ...children) => h(el, props, ...children)

export const Switch = converter(ReactRouter.Switch)

export const Route = converter(ReactRouter.Route)

export const Redirect = converter(ReactRouter.Redirect)

export const Div = converter('div')
```

Comment: If you don’t want to use JSX, why not just call `React.createElement(...)` directly? And if you want a named function for every element, why not just use JSX?

Comment: @MTCoster Why not just dump ketchup all over your spaghetti? I mean, it's closer to you than that fine marinara sauce... I'm not a <JSX /> hater, sometimes it results in cleaner looking code. Right now, for whatever reason, I'd just prefer to work with clean javascript and skip all the fancy nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, it appears that `njsx` has the best and most well thought out api.

Third-party library components can be individually wrapped in the nsjx default export.

You can even do point-free rendering (tested with ramda.compose):

```js
<Provider store={store}>
  <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

becomes:

```js
compose(
  Provider({ store }),
  PersistGate({ loading: null, persistor }),
  BrowserRouter,
  Route
)({ path: '/', component: App })()
```

From the [docs](https://github.com/uqbar-project/njsx):

## No-JSX

A pure function based interface for creating [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) components without *JSX* tags.

If you love *React* but don't quite like the embeded *HTML* tags this library may be what you are looking for. Construct your components with code only in a clean, declarative way.

```js
const myView = () =>
  div.app(
    div.header(
      img({src: logo, alt:'logo'}),
      h2('Welcome to NJSX')
    )
  )()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answers your question, because I'm not sure your question even is answerable.

What I *think* you want is a JavaScript equivalent of e.g. this Reagent (clojurescript React wrapper library) component:

```
(defn MyComponent [name]
  [:div.my-component
    [:p.my-component-content
      "Hello there "
      [:span.my-component-name 
        {:style {:color "red"}} 
        name]]])
```

For those not down with the cljs, it's a pure functional React component with a single prop (name) and renders out a div tag with css class 'my-component' that contains a p tag with a span etc. etc. Contrast that with this:

```
const MyComponent = ({name}) => (
  <div className="my-component">
    <p className="my-component-content">
      "Hello there " <span className="my-component-name" style="color:red;">name</span>
    </p>
  </div>
);
```

Not much difference at first blush except... in the ClojureScript version all of those declarative html bits are *first-class regular ClojureScript data structures*. You can introspect on them using all of the regular language constructs and tools, because unlike JSX it's not an embedded DSL. You can kinda sorta get this out of JSX by adding refs, but it's not pretty.

Note that the explicit `React.createElement` version doesn't have this problem, it's objects all the way down and you have references in the lexical scope like you would for any other binding. But you lose declarative-ness: the explicit version is far more verbose (and if you want the benefits you have to use it for everything).

I'm not sure there is a way to have your cake (declarative terseness) and eat it too (first-class language constructs) in JavaScript React. Since Facebook pays some very talented engineers a lot of money to work on this exact problem, and their solution was to embed JSX as a DSL, I'm guessing no. But it would be cool if you could.

One last point on that though.

Be careful about straying too far from the beaten path. If you do something too weird someone else is going come along (maybe even future you) and look at some weird thing you did for the sake of developer ergonomics and say "WTF I can't even *read* this hot garbage". Innovation happens in that space, but so does a lot of disasters.

Comment: Thanks, seems I'm in outer-space a lot these days!

Comment: @RichardForrester well, "there's got to be a better way to do this crap" is a perfectly rational response to the state of programming in 2018, and "then why hasn't someone already done it?" is a perfectly rational counter-question. :)